# OpenGL 4.1 Learning Resources

Tags: opengl

What are some good resources for learning OpenGL 4.1 aimed at someone relatively new to graphics programming?

I'm aware that this was asked before, but I would think that ~9 months would give us more.

I know that [OpenGL Programming Guide: The Official Guide to Learning OpenGL, Versions 4.1 (8th Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321773039) is coming out apparently in October, but is there anything else?  It seems like there's been some major changes, and I'd hate to feel like my time studying until this book release was wasted.  Sites can work too, provided they are focusing on 4.1.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to learn OpenGL 4.1? Why not learn an older version first and support old OSes? Take a look at [OpenGL Super Bible](http://www.starstonesoftware.com/OpenGL/). I'm reading OpenGL Super Bible first edition but probably you find that a bit old-fashioned.

Comment: @Midas - My understanding is that 4.1 is much better arranged/combined than earlier versions.  This makes it useful for desktop or mobile.  I also like to learn the latest because I think that's what a company would expect me to be good at.  If either of these assumptions are off the mark, please let me know.

Comment: Please, please do not use nehe to learn modern OpenGL :/ It is hopelessly outdated. Given the lack of books updated for OpenGL4.1 at this point, I think your best bet is good OpenGL books in general (for example here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926357/c-opengl-books/5935977#5935977) and the specifications to fill in the new stuff (mostly programmable tesselation stages)

Comment: The design of OpenGL 3.x+ probably would make it efficient for mobile... but I haven't heard of any mobile devices supporting it.  Even fat mobile devices such as Intel Atom don't.  I'd love to see an example of even one.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I mean to say that opengl ES and opengl have a more similar instruction set at 4.1, making learning the instruction more effective.  Someone can correct me if this is wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenGL 4.x learning resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439229/opengl-4-x-learning-resources)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to learn graphics programming properly then OGL 4.1 is the place to start these days, but if as a beginner you want to hack stuff out then i'd advise you take an easier route (DirectX). Your programming skills have to up there and especially your maths skills aswell (linear algebra). Get a copy of the Spec and the Red/Orange and Blue books, a good book on mathematics for 3d graphics and prepare for alot of pain, pure 4.1 from scratch is hard.

Don't worry about not getting the latest edition of the red book, 3.3->4.1 didn't change a huge amount in terms of new features or paradigm, mainly just removing deprecated functionality.

Mesh loaders can be fulfilled by OpenCTM, GXBase is also quite good.

Don't bother learning OGL prior to 4.1, it's based on a deprecated paradigm and so you will waste time learning stuff that is officially out of date. The super bible has a good amount of code that will help you along the way.

Comment: I've got programming and linear algebra covered.  My main concern is avoiding learning antiquated opengl practices.  You'd say 3.3 is an acceptable start?

Comment: yea the paradigm is the same just 4.1 goes alot further. latest edition of the superbible is very good.